# Enable debug in Camunda

Tags: camunda, catalina, camunda-modeler, catalina.out

I would like to know if there is a way to enable Camunda debug?
As I can only see the logs related to bpmn file deploy, as well as errors that could occur, in catalina.out file.

My point is, I would like to debug the Rest API requests and responses that I make, in order to see all steps that are being made, from Camunda Modeler (where bpmn file is deployed to the engine) to Cockpit (where the process-definition is afterwards started)?
I’m using Tomcat as server.

Comment: There is nothing special about debugging camunda .. it is just another java lib running in your tomcat ... if you are not familiar with debugging tomcat: https://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging of basically everything done by engine by adjusting logback properties:
[described here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/user-guide/logging/#logging-categories)